# Application crahses while loading a big PDF

Tags: android, pdf, out-of-memory

Anyone knows how to load big pdf file in Android? I use "android-pdf-viewer" to load that kind of file. It works when the file is small. But once the file is too big(150M eg.),it throws OOM exception.

```
11-28 21:07:43.596 7844-8419/com.example.caoweizhao.readerapp E/art: Out 
of memory: Heap Size=192MB, Allocated=83MB, Capacity=192MB
11-28 21:07:43.596 7844-8419/com.example.caoweizhao.readerapp W/art: 
Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 134209548 byte 
allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 108MB until OOM"
11-28 21:07:43.607 7844-7844/com.example.caoweizhao.readerapp E/PDFView: load pdf error
                                                                     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 134209548 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 108MB until OOM
                                                                         at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:91)
                                                                         at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:201)
                                                                         at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.util.Util.toByteArray(Util.java:37)
                                                                         at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.source.InputStreamSource.createDocument(InputStreamSource.java:37)
                                                                         at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:53)
                                                                         at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:25)
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

11

Comment: Please also post exception with log

Comment: I have used MuPDF library in a project before, aside the build process, it is fairly good for all intents and purposes, so if you won't mind, it is a good recommendation.

Comment: In your manifest under application put android:largeHeap="true".

Comment: @KulsDroid It works!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your **AndroidManifest.xml** file, add `android:largeHeap="true"` in the application tag